# put and delete problem in restfull in laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel, http-delete, http-put

put and delete not work in my laravel project when i want to implement Restfull api . actualy when I use postman delete and put work fine. but when use react cant access them. and i get a 404 error.

Comment: Share your code from controller and routs for better overview.

Answer (score 0):

Have you put `_method:delete or put` in your passed data in ajax?

Answer (score 0):

You need to spoof any method except for GET and POST - https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#form-method-spoofing

For ajax requests, you need to add

```
data: {
    ...
    _method: 'PUT' // or 'DELETE'
}
```

to your data set.